# Implementation of function execve (unistd.h)

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls, unistd.h, execve

How can I see the implementation of function execve (under x86_64 Linux), it is in the library unistd?
I want this because I want to know how can I call an external program using assembler, without calling execve.
I know that there is a syscall named execve, but I don't know how can I use it.

How can I put a variable of type char * and type char * [] into registers ?

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of the `execve()` function in userspace looks something like:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char * const argv[], char * const envp[]) {
    return syscall(SYS_execve, filename, argv, envp);
}
```

All of the actual "work" is done in the kernel. There's nothing particularly interesting happening in libc, besides perhaps some threading cleanup.

Comment: Thanks you all, but how can I put a variable of type char * and type char * [] into registers ?, I only know how to make the write and exit syscall, for example, when I make a write syscall, I have to put the pointer into a register and the buffer size into another , but how can I do it now?

Comment: No different than before -- put the pointers to the filename, argument array, and environment array in three registers. The latter two should simply be pointers to the start of arrays of `char *`, terminated by NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a look at the kernel sources (more specifically: arch/YOUR-ARCH/kernel/head*.S) for the system call convention on your architecture (registers and/or stack for the syscall number and the parameters).

On ARM, for example, you would load `__NR_execve` into r7, load the arguments into r0, r1, r2 and then use `swi 0`. You might be interested in [this explantion of ARM EABI syscalls](http://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort#System_call_interface) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real straightforward implementation of system calls in the source code to glibc - this is generated at build time from various files defining the system call numbers.

The relevant information can be found in [sysdep.h](http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h) if you understand it, except for the actual system call numbers (you want `__NR_execve` with, IIRC, `#include <asm/unistd.h>` - I can't recall offhand what it is on x86_64).

The system call number goes in %rax, and the arguments go in %rdi %rsi %rdx. All this information (including stack alignment and something about register usage by the kernel) is commented in sysdep.h.