# Run a process from C with a seccomp profile

Tags: linux, system-calls, seccomp

I want to run a process with a seccomp profile applied to it (can be from C, terminal, etc.). In particular, I would like the target command to not be allowed to read and write any files, and it can just print to the console. The temporary C outline I have is this:

```
int main() {
    scmp_filter_ctx filter = load_filter();
    seccomp_load(filter);
    // execl([sample command with arguments], 0);
    execl("ls", 0)
}
```

The problem I am having is that the `execl` uses some sys calls that are blocked in my profile. How can I ensure that the only gets applied only to the `[sample command with arguments]`. Again, this does not have to be in C. Basically, I want to run some executables, and apply `seccomp` to those processes. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

`exec*` calls are frontend to `execve`, which implementation in user space looks like this:

```
int execve(const char *filename, char * const argv[], char * const envp[]) {
    return syscall(SYS_execve, filename, argv, envp);
}
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381910/544721

Therefore, you may want to instrument your desired binary to execute seccomp filters code after being loaded. e.g.  via binary instrumentation (to add extra code) of actual binary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem. As already pointed out, `execl()` is a library function that calls [`execve(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). However, presuming that the program you are launching is dynamically linked (e.g., `ls` as above), your seccomp filter would also need to allow all of the system calls that the dynamic linker ([`ld.so(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)) employs to load shared libraries needed by the program. Examples of such system calls (which may vary according to the version of the dynamic linker on your system) are `access()`, `openat()`, `close()`, `read()`, `mmap()`, `mprotect()`, and more. (You can see examples of those systems calls by doing an [`strace(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) of a simple "hello world" C program.

As [Grzegorz Wierzowiecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544721/grzegorz-wierzowiecki) points out, your only really alternative is to instrument (modify) the target program so that it loads a filter after it has been launched. (There are tricks involving the use of `LD_PRELOAD`, but these are [not foolproof](https://lore.kernel.org/all/202010281500.855B950FE@keescook/T/#mce16cb0deb8ea2ad10c1bc3697241006559876b5).)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your seccomp filter so that it only allows that exact call to execve. It is possible to check arguments for equality.

Comment: This is not correct. The various arguments to `execve()` are strings (or arrays of pointers to strings), and in a seccomp filter it is not possible to dereference pointer arguments and check what they point to.

Comment: Right but you could create the filter with hard-coded pointer addresses into read-only memory.